# Web App on Azure loaded slow after applying custom domain

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, web-hosting

I just started hosting my website on Azure. Initially when uploading and hosting the website on xxxx.azurewebsites.net, the performance and response was great. After adding a custom domain (Bought from Godaddy), the performance became worst and it would take 1 min for a page to load.

xxxx.azurewebsites.net -> loaded in few seconds

xxxx.com -> loaded in almost a minute

Is there anything im missing here? In General Configuration, I have enabled Always On but the performance is still the same for custom domains.

Custom Domains set up :
[image]

In Chrome Network tools, I can see that the connection is stalled for at least 1 minutes. Not sure what causing this.

[image]

Comment: have you added all the mappings correctly ? can you paste how your records look on godaddy?

Comment: have you generated your own SSL certificate?

Comment: Has this problem been solved? Is there still this phenomenon? Visit both `xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net` and `customdomain.com` at the same time. Is the first visit fast, but the second still slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the performance is (very) bad only with the custom domain, chances are DNS is either not setup correctly, or hosted on a (very) slow DNS host. Of course, it might be something else altogether.

Here's a few things that can help you determine the issue:

- Check if there's any logic in your web app that might be retried or waiting for a response it is not getting when you're connecting to it through the domain name.
- Check the speed of your DNS, for instance by using [Ultratools' DNS Speed Test](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsHostingSpeed).

> The DNS hosting speed tool will give you valuable DNS performance information for each level in the DNS tree to assist with performance evaluations and performance troubleshooting.

- Run this from a command line and see information about how to get to your domain:

```
nslookup
> set debug
<your-domain-name>
```

- Consider adding a service like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) to your website.

> Protect and accelerate your websites, apps, and teams.

- Run [webhint](https://webhint.io/) (or any other tool that gives you insight) on your custom domain.

It does more than just performance:

> webhint is a customizable linting tool that helps you improve your site's accessibility, speed, cross-browser compatibility, and more by checking your code for best practices and common errors.