# .Net Core 3.1 Web API latency issue with Azure App Servce

Tags: c#, azure

I have a web application built on top of Asp.net core 2.1 Web API , Angular, Azure SQL Server DB, Entity Framework 2.1.4 . The application is hosted it in the Azure AppService (please assume the URL as “abctest.azurewebsites.net”) . Also I have configured a custom domain (will call it as “abctest.com”).
The application is working fine with out any issue .

I tried to Migrate this “.net core 2.1” Web API to “.net core 3.1” . Also I upgrade my EF version from “2.1.4” to “2.2.6” . Everything works fine in the local environment . But after I published this build to my Azure App service , I am facing some issues as mentioned below .

The API is having some latency to return the result after updating an records

- This is happening only when I am using the custom domain end point
  “abctest.com”. But it is not throwing any error, instead it is
  fetching the old record (just before the update).
- Even I have checked the DBs call through the profiler, and there I am
  not able to find those DB calls . But after some 2-3 minutes , I am
  getting those records and able to see the DB calls through the
  profiler.
- Also I have checked the “**request**” through the    application
  insights , when I am getting the old records I am not    able to find
  the request logs there. That looks like, it is not even    hitting my
  Azure app service site from the custom domain. Even we    tried to
  roll back the framework to “.net core 2.1” and still it    works fine
  with the same AppService and custom domain.

***This issue is not happening with the direct azure website URL (“abctest.azurewebsites.net”) :It is working fine without any issue .
But when the application was running in “.net Core 2.1” , it was working fine with both Azure site URL and custom domain URL.***

It will be very helpful if some one able to help to figure out the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

If the performance is (very) bad only with the custom domain, chances are DNS is either not setup correctly, or hosted on a (very) slow DNS host. Of course, it might be something else altogether.

Here's a few things that can help you determine the issue:

- Check if there's any logic in your web app that might be retried or
  waiting for a response it is not getting when you're connecting to it
  through the domain name.
- Check the speed of your DNS, for instance by using Ultratools' DNS
  Speed Test.

> The DNS hosting speed tool will give you valuable DNS performance
> information for each level in the DNS tree to assist with performance
> evaluations and performance troubleshooting.

- Run this from a command line and see information about how to get to
  your domain:

  nslookup
  set debug
- Consider adding a service like Cloudflare to your website.

> Protect and accelerate your websites, apps, and teams.

- Run webhint (or any other tool that gives you insight) on your custom
  domain.

It does more than just performance:

> webhint is a customizable linting tool that helps you improve your
> site's accessibility, speed, cross-browser compatibility, and more by
> checking your code for best practices and common errors.

Check out rickvdbosch's answer on the same - [Web App on Azure loaded slow after applying custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929095/web-app-on-azure-loaded-slow-after-applying-custom-domain)